# Laravel - Validation - Require if field is null

Tags: php, validation, laravel, require

Let's say I have this html code:

```
<input type="email" name="email">
<input type="password" name="password">
```

Or this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="1">
```

(If the user is logged in, only the `user_id` field will be shown. else - the credentials fields).

When I create a request, there's a validation that checks the user. if the field `user_id` exists (i.e if `user_id` exists in the users table), then there's no need to require `email` and `password` inputs. If there's no `user_id`, then the `email` and `password` fields will be required.

In other words, I want to do something like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'user_id'   => 'exists:users,id',
        'email'     => 'required_if_null:user_id|email|...',
        'password'  => 'required_if_null:user_id|...'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

After reading the Validation docs again, I found a solution. I just needed to do the opposite, using the `required_without` validation:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'user_id'       => 'exists:users,id',
        'email'         => 'required_without:user_id|email|unique:users,email',
        'password'      => 'required_without:user_id',
}
```

Comment: how would you write `update` rules then when it uses `sometimes` instead of `required`? there doen't seem to be `sometimes_without`